# Is nirvana a process?

Tags: mahayana, nirvana

I have often been told that nirvana is not a state or entity, because there are no real states or entities in Mahayana Buddhism.

If so, is that nirvanisation (a word I've seen for the process of coming to enlightenment) a state for those that undergo it?

Comment: i can cite for the 1st clause, if you like?

Comment: Why is Nirvana not state?

Comment: @ruben2020 just a well known piece of scholarship, i think. let me find st to cite

Comment: @ruben2020 looks like i can't find the sd scholarship, and it's just something i've been repeatedly told by a scholar. hm, not sure about the question, now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nirvana cannot be a process because this would make Nirvana 'conditioned'.

Nirvana is a state (*dhamma*; *ṭhānaṃ*) or a sense object/base (*ayatana*; Udana 8.1).

> *There is, bhikkhus, that **base** (**ayatana**) where there is no earth, no water, no fire, no air; no base consisting of the infinity of space, no base
>   consisting of the infinity of consciousness, no base consisting of
>   nothingness, no base consisting of
>   neither-perception-nor-non-perception; neither this world nor another
>   world nor both; neither sun nor moon. Here, bhikkhus, I say there is
>   no coming, no going, no staying, no deceasing, no uprising. Not fixed,
>   not movable, it has no support. Just this is the end of suffering. Ud
>   8.1*
>
> ---
>
> *'This **Dhamma** that I have attained is deep, hard to see, hard to realize, peaceful, refined, beyond the scope of conjecture, subtle,
>   to-be-experienced by the wise. But this generation delights in
>   attachment, is excited by attachment, enjoys attachment. For a
>   generation delighting in attachment, excited by attachment, enjoying
>   attachment, this/that conditionality & dependent co-arising are hard
>   to see. This **state** (**ṭhānaṃ**), too, is hard to see: the calming of all
>   fabrications, the relinquishment of all acquisitions, the ending of
>   craving; dispassion; cessation; **Nibbana**. MN 26*
>
> ---
>
> [ṭhāna](https://suttacentral.net/define/%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na)
>
> standing; the act of standing, being fixed or stationary; continuance.
>   a place; a locality; a spot; a site; a location; a suitable place; a
>   worthy object. region, sphere; metaphysical or spiritual state.
>   situation; station; office; position. position; state. occasion; case,
>   occurrence; matter. quality; attribute, characteristic. ground, basis;
>   reason, cause. stance; standpoint; condition.

Comment: well your answer is fine, a little motontonic, as you avoid the non cogntiion of emptiness, non abiding, and the term "nirvanised" which was what i was getting at the question. but i can't see a better one

Comment: Nirvana & emptiness are cognitions & abidings (MN 151), at least in Pali Buddhism. Regards